# Xcode: iPhone screenshots no longer work

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

I can't be sure when this stopped working because I haven't used it for a while, but it was possibly since I upgraded to the 3.2 SDK.  In Organizer, when I select the "Screenshots" tab and press "Capture", nothing happens.

I've tried this with three different devices and I've restarted my Mac.  What's happened, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just to make certain, your devices are running 3.1.3 (iPhones) and 3.2 (iPad), right? You have not upgraded to the beta for iPhone, correct?

Comment: Same thing for me. 3.2 SDK. Although my ipod touch is still running 3.1.2 (don't ask...). I've been resorting to just using the home+sleep button combo on my device then copying the photos off the device. Screenshots do work from organizer (4 me) in xCode 3.2.3 (Pre-release) that comes with SDK 4b3.

Comment: I have not installed any beta on my devices.  I have the 4.0b1 SDK installed but in a separate location.  Screenshot does not work for that either.  Guess I will try beta 3 now it's available.

Comment: Same for me, and I also have the beta installed in a separate location. However I have noticed that despite that some things about XCode have changed - for example when I try to view a code sample from the Document Viewer it opens in the beta version of XCode. So I'm assuming that the same thing is causing this screenshots problem.

Comment: Have you tried resinstalling the developer tools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have the solution for your problem, but here's a workaround:

Use the device to make your screenshots (press the home and lock buttons simultaneously). The resulting screenshot will be saved on the device.

To transfer the screenshot to your desktop don't use slow-ish iPhoto or iTunes to synchronize. Instead import the images using Preview.app. There's a command in the file menu to import images from your iPhone when it's connected.

Comment: Recommended! I use it the same way.

Comment: http://jehiah.cz/archive/iphone-simulator-screenshots this works nicely to get screenshots from the simulator itself. It's much quicker than using the device.

Comment: Spiffy! I didn't know about the Preview import.

Answer (score 3):

On xcode 4.0 (+), you can go to organizer and create a screenshot of device.

Window -> Organizer -> click the device tab and then screenshot button.

Comment: I can't find any screenshot button.

Comment: click on the ipad section on the left(on the organizer window), expand that menu, and click on screenshot icon. Click on the screenshot icon(on the left menu), you'll see 'New Screenshot' button on the bottom left window. The ipad device needs to be connected when you do this,

Answer (score 0):

Hold command-shift-4. Then drag it across the iPhone screen. This key combination give you the ability to take a screen shot with the size you want.